# Is it possible to SSH to another machine over university Wi-Fi?

Tags: networking, ssh

I would like to set up an SSH server on a machine on a university wireless network and be able to access it from a client on the same university network. I've done this over a local area network before, but I don't know if the process is different over the university network, which uses Eduroam. From what I can gather Eduroam works differently from a LAN, but I don't know where to start in figuring out how use SSH on it. Is this even possible?

Comment: We dont work in your universities IT department, so we cannot say what will and wont work.  I would expect it to work, but you dont know until you try.  If it doesnt work, they you can ask a specific question.

Comment: chances are, universities wifi would isolate clients

Comment: @JaromandaX Im sure every school has different setups.  However, students do have to connect to servers to and websites in different departments.  They would be doing this from their dorms, library, deparmental computers, etc all from WiFi.

Comment: yeah, that's why I didn't say universities DEFINITELY would isolate wifi clients - but, the OP needs to try as you said @Keltari - we can't try for her